# GetTransactionDetails PayPal SOAP API using PHP

Tags: php, soap, paypal

I've been asked to retrieve the buyer's email address via the PayPal API using a transaction ID.  I can see that I can use the GetTransactionDetails function to do this.

I've managed to login using the credentials I've been given using SOAP but when it comes to running GetTransactionDetails, I'm getting errors.

Here's my code:

```
$user = "XXXXXX";
$pass = "XXXXXX";
$sign = "XXXXXX";

$socket_context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('protocol_version'  => 1.0)));
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl", array('exceptions' => 0,'stream_context' => $socket_context,'trace' => 1)); 

$params = array(
    "Username" => $user, 
    "Password" => $pass, 
    "Signature" => $sign);

$credentials = new stdClass();
$credentials->Credentials = new SoapVar(
                            $params, 
                            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
                            'Credentials');

$headers = new SoapVar(
           $credentials, 
           SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
           'CustomSecurityHeaderType', 
           'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');

$client->__setSoapHeaders(
         new SoapHeader(
             'urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI', 
             'RequesterCredentials', 
             $headers)
         );

if (is_soap_fault($credentials)) {
    print "SOAP Fault: $credentials->faultcode, $credentials->faultstring<br />";
} else {
    print "logged in";
}

$args = array(
        "Version" => "124.0", 
        "TransactionID" => "12345ABCDE"); 
$GetTransactionDetailsRequest = new stdClass();
$GetTransactionDetailsRequest->GetTransactionDetailsRequest = new SoapVar(
                               $args, 
                               SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
                               'GetTransactionDetailsRequestType', 
                               'urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI');
$params = new SoapVar(
          $GetTransactionDetailsRequest, 
          SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
          'GetTransactionDetailsRequest');
$result = $client->GetTransactionDetails($params);
print "<pre>";
print_r($result);
print "</pre>";
```

And this is the error I'm seeing after running it:

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => Bad Request
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /location/to/file.php
    [line:protected] => 42
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [function] => __doRequest
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    
                            [1] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/
                            [2] => 
                            [3] => 1
                            [4] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /location/to/file.php
                    [line] => 42
                    [function] => __call
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => GetTransactionDetails
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SoapVar Object
                                        (
                                            [enc_type] => 301
                                            [enc_value] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [GetTransactionDetailsRequest] => SoapVar Object
                                                        (
                                                            [enc_type] => 301
                                                            [enc_value] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [Version] => 124.0
                                                                    [TransactionID] => 12345ABCDE
                                                                )

                                                            [enc_stype] => GetTransactionDetailsRequestType
                                                            [enc_ns] => urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [enc_stype] => GetTransactionDetailsRequest
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /location/to/file.php
                    [line] => 42
                    [function] => GetTransactionDetails
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SoapVar Object
                                (
                                    [enc_type] => 301
                                    [enc_value] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [GetTransactionDetailsRequest] => SoapVar Object
                                                (
                                                    [enc_type] => 301
                                                    [enc_value] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Version] => 124.0
                                                            [TransactionID] => 12345ABCDE
                                                        )

                                                    [enc_stype] => GetTransactionDetailsRequestType
                                                    [enc_ns] => urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [enc_stype] => GetTransactionDetailsRequest
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [faultstring] => Bad Request
    [faultcode] => HTTP
)
```

The line it's failing on is:

```
$result = $client->GetTransactionDetails($params);
```

I've never worked with the PayPal API before and I've scraped code from several different examples so if someone knows of a better way to do this, that would be great!

NOTES:

- I've made up the login details, location of file and TransactionID
  for this post.
- The real TransactionID is correct, I've double checked it in PayPal
  directly
- The Version number is from the WSDL (it states that number at the
  beginning)
- I only added $socket_context because without it, it came back
  saying "Error Fetching http headers".

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, it turns out the API was defaulting the Sandbox Endpoint!  I've added the following code to my script right after I call the SoapClient:

```
$client->__setLocation('https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/');
```

Now it works!